# Method Not found exception after changing connection from MongoDB to Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

My application structure is fairly simple as per below -

1. **EmailService** project which is an ASP.NET website project
2. **EventLogging** is a class assembly containing code to log events and
       exceptions in our MongoDB. This project is referenced from
       EmailService project.

MongoDB driver and nuget packages are referenced within EventLogging project only. (Packages are - MongoDB.Bson, MongDB.Driver, MongoDB.Driver.Core).

This all works perfectly fine. EmailService is able to connect with MongoDB instance which is hosted in our intranet, and also able to insert records in MongoDB collections.

Currently we are in process of replacing the on-premise MongoDB with the Azure Cosmos DB.

We have updated code in EventLogging library to use Cosmos DB settings:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(MongoUrl.Create(CONNECTION_STRING));
SslSettings ssl = new SslSettings();
ssl.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
settings.SslSettings = ssl;
return new MongoClient(settings);
```

Connection string is now pointing to Azure Cosmos DB instance.

While trying to insert the items into the collection, the application throws following exception during call to `InsertOne` or `InsertOneAsync` methods of MongoRepository:

> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection`1.InsertOneAsync(!0,
>   MongoDB.Driver.InsertOneOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken)'

I could manage to fix the issue by installing same Mongo drivers to the EmailService project. That means, I have referenced MongoDB.Bson, MongoDB.Driver, and MongoDB.Driver.Core nuget packages in the EmailService project, even though they are already there in the EventLogging project.

While the issue is resolved, I am still concerned that why I have to install same packages in the EmailService project, whereas earlier it was all working fine with the packages only in EventLogging project.

Can anyone please share views on this?

Comment: I am still concerned that why I have to install same packages in the EmailService project, because the libraries depended on some external another libraries, suppose A and B are projs ,A refrenced in B , A need C to be run then C should be referenced in B also, C is external lib.

Comment: Project C is an external library. Project B is having a reference of Project C. Project A is having a reference of Project B. Project A always uses Project B to access any member/ call any method of Project C. So why I need to add reference of Project C in Project A. Also, in context of this question, if it is required then why it was not required when connecting with MongoDB, and why suddenly it started breaking without the references when connecting with Cosmos DB?